# Multilingual ui using Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, multilingual

i'm working on a CRM that should work on different countries

this is my first time using Laravel so i'm bit confused

my database looks like this:

**Language**

- id
- name
- short_name (en,ru etc)

**Dictionary**

- id
- label (sign_in,forgot_password etc)
- value ('Sign In','Вход' etc )
- language_id

i thought about working this way:

http://domain.com/en

http://domain.com/ru

http://domain.com/en/users

http://domain.com/ru/users

if user go to http://domain.com so it will redirect him by this steps:

1. if the user logged in the past and has cookie with his language
2. if there is no cookie get the country of the user by his IP
3. if the country's language is not recognized in the Languages table redirect the user to default language that set on the config/app.php => 'locale' => 'default language'

i wonder if there is any way to do that without sending the language variable in every function in the controllers,
what do i mean?

i mean that i **dont** wont my routes and my controllers to look like this:

**Routes**

```
Route::get('/{locale}', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm');  
Route::get('/{locale}/users/', 'UsersController@index');
Route::get('/{locale}/users/view/{id}', 'UsersController@viewUser');
```

**Controllers**

```
public function showLoginForm($locale)
{
    App::setLocale($locale);
    return view('auth.login');
}
...
public function index($locale)
{
    App::setLocale($locale);
    return view('users.index');
}
...
```

i want it to work in the background without me setting the language every time and setting the routes,

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Middleware would perhaps be the way to go for this. As you're already planning on using a cookie to store the user's locale you could just create middleware which is registered to the web route group (which is applied to all routes by default).

Then within your middleware class just call the setLocale method on App and pass the cookie.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
    App::setLocale($request->cookie('locale'));

    return $next($request);
}
```

If you haven't worked with middleware before, as always the Laravel docs are great: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/middleware.

Comment: alex thank you, i think i will remove the language var from the url and use only cookies

Comment: Glad I could help, if in future you wanted to still use the language variable you could wrap your routes in a route group which has the locale as a prefix:

`Route::group(['prefix' => '{locale}'], function() { // Routes here });` 

You could just include whichever routes required the locale within that group so you didn't have to assign it in every method and just ignore it. I'm sure there's a better way of doing it but none that I can think of right now.

Comment: Alex you are the best ! ;)